# Resend AJAX request with link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there anyway to reload just the AJAX request, so that it updates the content pulled from the external site in the code below?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var mySearch = $('input#id_search').quicksearch('#content table', { clearSearch: '#clearsearch', });
        var container = $('#content');
        function doAjax(url) {
            if (url.match('^http')) {
                $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?"+
                    "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22"+
                    encodeURIComponent(url)+
                    "%22&format=xml'&callback=?", 
                function (data) {
                if (data.results[0]) {
                    var fullResponse = $(filterData(data.results[0])),
                       justTable = fullResponse.find("table");
                    container.append(justTable);
                    mySearch.cache();
                    $('.loading').fadeOut();
                } else {
                    var errormsg = '<p>Error: could not load the page.</p>';
                    container.html(errormsg);
                }
                });
            } else {
                $('#content').load(url);
            }
        }
        function filterData(data) {
            data = data.replace(/<?\/body[^>]*>/g, '');
            data = data.replace(/[\r|\n]+/g, '');
            data = data.replace(/<--[\S\s]*?-->/g, '');
            data = data.replace(/<noscript[^>]*>[\S\s]*?<\/noscript>/g, '');
            data = data.replace(/<script[^>]*>[\S\s]*?<\/script>/g, '');
            data = data.replace(/<script.*\/>/, '');
            data = data.replace(/<img[^>]*>/g, '');
            return data;
        }
        doAjax('link');
    });
```

Right now I have a button which reloads the entire page, but I just want to reload the AJAX request. Is this even possible?

*Edit: I need to specify more. While it can easily call the AJAX again, can it also replace the info that is already there?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to call the doAjax function again on button click...

```
$("#buttonID").on("click", function() {
    doAjax("link");
});
```

Add that into the above document.ready code and set the button ID correspondingly.

Then change

```
container.append(justTable);
```

to

```
container.html(justTable);
```

Comment: Is there any way it can also replace the info that's already there? Sorry, I should have specified more in the op.

Comment: Instead of container.append(justTable) do container.html(justTable) - that will replace any existing data.

Comment: Just a note: `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and is the same in this case as `.bind()`. http://api.jquery.com/on

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that, Jasper.  I tend to try and use the most up-to-date version and sometimes forget that that's not always an option for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

In your `doAjax` function you append HTML onto an element. If you overwrite the element's HTML instead of appending to it then the HTML will be "refreshed" each time the `doAjax` function runs:

Simply change:

```
container.append(justTable);
```

To:

```
container.html(justTable);
```

And of-course you can bind a `click` event handler to a link (or any element) like the rest of the answers show. Make sure you bind the `click` event in the proper scope (inside the `document.ready` event handler) so the `doAjax` function will be accessible from the `click` event handler.